# Unable to load image of BIRT report in Iframe due to content security policy

Tags: java, iframe, struts2, content-security-policy

I am getting the following error message when tried to load a BIRT report in an iframe. I am getting the following error in the developer console.

> Error Message:
>
> "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://someserver.com/payrollRecon/StatisticsReport_>efreshReport.action' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure plugin resource 'http://someserver.com/birt/preview?__sessionId=20190410_063733_547&__imageid=custom272bcb9e16a06cfee3f1.svg'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

I have the content-security-policy header set with the following:

```
upgrade-insecure-requests; default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://someserver.com/birt/ https://someserver.com/birtuat/; object-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://someserver.com/birt/ https://someserver.com/birtuat/; img-src *; frame-src 'self' https://someserver.com/birt/ https://someserver.com/birtuat/ https:; font-src 'self' data:; connect-src 'self'
```

the upgrade-insecure-request CSP directive supposed to upgrade the URL to https but for some reason, it is not upgrading.

upgrade-insecure-request added to csp directive to upgrade the requests to https. But not working.

Comment: I managed to upgrade the url to https by modifying the code in BIRT report jsp files. I modified the RequesterFragment.jsp, RunFragment.jsp and FramesetFragment.jsp files to upgrade the request to https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to upgrade the url to https by modifying the code in BIRT report jsp files. I modified the RequesterFragment.jsp, RunFragment.jsp and FramesetFragment.jsp files to upgrade the request to https.

added https schema to baseHref in the above files.